# Unable to send message from Producer to Consumer

Tags: windows, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-producer-api

`kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:2181 --topic baeldung`
`kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic baeldung`

Message is not going from producer to consumer.

Comment: Voting to close as typo. 2181 => 9092

Answer (score 1):

In the consumer you've mistakenly used zookeeper port 2181. It has to be `localhost:9092`

Comment: If using `--zookeeper localhost:2181`  instead, then it might work, but not in latest releases where that support was removed, I believe. In earlier releases , it would additionally require adding `--new-consumer` option, which was added around 0.10 release

Comment: Yep, I assumed it's one of the newer releases.

Answer (score 1):

Consumer Script:

> kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:2181 --topic
>   baeldung

Producer Script :

> kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic
>   baeldung

In above commands, broker addresses are different. Producer seems to have correct address `localhost:9092` while consumer script has zookeeper address `localhost:2181`. Change it to `localhost:9092` like this ::

```
kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092--topic baeldung
```

Answer (score 1):

Commands you need in order to run producer and consumer:

> **Cosumer**:
>
> ```
> kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic baeldung
> ```
>
> **Producer**
>
> ```
> kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic baeldung
> ```

If you want to consume messages from the beginning, include `--from-beginning` in consumer, otherwise it will consume latest messages by default.

If you add more brokers to your cluster, in order to consume/produce from all brokers just add your brokers ports like: `localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094`